RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-3 (get_current_power)'
I would like to handle multiple task concurrently. However, the original code tends to cause some delay while waiting for the schedule task. Then, when threading is used, the runtime error is resulted. Anyone can help me with this problem?
**Here are my original codes:**

This codes leads to some delay when the schedule task is being carried out

import asyncio
import control
import plug
import time
import schedule
import time
from inputimeout import inputimeout
import lgpio
import blynk_control
import blynk_switch
from threading import Thread

###Variables###
threshold = 400
sw = '0 0 0 0 0'
sw_control = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
EMERGENCY = 23
current_data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
h = lgpio.gpiochip_open(0)
lgpio.gpio_claim_output(h, EMERGENCY)

def get_data():
    data = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(plug.plug_data())
    return data

def get_usage():
    usage = get_data()
    usage = usage[1]
    return usage

def get_current_power():
    current_power = get_data()
    current_power = current_power[2]
    return current_power

def total_power_reading():
    reading = get_current_power()
    total_power_reading = 0
    for i in range(len(reading)):
        total_power_reading += reading[i]
    
    return total_power_reading

def plug_reading():
    global current_data
    previous_data = current_data
    current_data = get_current_power()
    print(f'current_data:{current_data}')
    print(f'previous_data: {previous_data}')
    print(f'Total Power: {total_power_reading()}')
    if previous_data == current_data:
        print("Emergency!!!!")
        lgpio.gpio_write(h,EMERGENCY,1)
    else:
        lgpio.gpio_write(h,EMERGENCY,0)

def switch_control():
        global sw
        global sw_control


        previous_sw = sw_control
        sw_control = blynk_switch.main()
        if len(sw_control) == 1:
            sw_control[1:5] = previous_sw[1:5]
        elif len(sw_control)==2:
            sw_control[2:5] = previous_sw[2:5]
        elif len(sw_control)==3:
            sw_control[3:5] = previous_sw[3:5]
        elif len(sw_control)==4:
            print(sw_control)
            sw_control[4:5] = previous_sw[4:5]
        elif len(sw_control)==0:
            sw_control[0:5] = previous_sw[0:5]

def power_monitoring():
    global sw_control, threshold
    print(f'Totap Power: {total_power_reading()}')

    if (total_power_reading()>threshold):
        current_power = get_current_power()
        num = current_power.index(max(current_power))
        sw_control[num] = '0'

schedule.every(2).seconds.do(power_monitoring)
schedule.every(20).seconds.do(plug_reading)
schedule.every(5).seconds.do(blynk_control.main)
def main_1():
    # Loop to run the scheduler continuously
    global sw_control
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(control.plug_data(sw_control[0],sw_control[1],sw_control[2],sw_control[3],sw_control[4]))
        print(f'Switch is {sw_control}')
        switch_control()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_1()

Modified code:
This codes caused the runtime error.
import asyncio
import control
import plug
import time
import schedule
import time
from inputimeout import inputimeout
import lgpio
import blynk_control
import blynk_switch
from threading import Thread

###Variables###
threshold = 400
sw = '0 0 0 0 0'
sw_control = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
EMERGENCY = 23
current_data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
h = lgpio.gpiochip_open(0)
lgpio.gpio_claim_output(h, EMERGENCY)

def get_data():
    data = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(plug.plug_data())
    return data

def get_usage():
    usage = get_data()
    usage = usage[1]
    return usage

def get_current_power():
    current_power = get_data()
    current_power = current_power[2]
    return current_power

def total_power_reading():
    reading = get_current_power()
    total_power_reading = 0
    for i in range(len(reading)):
        total_power_reading += reading[i]
    
    return total_power_reading

def plug_reading():
    global current_data
    previous_data = current_data
    current_data = get_current_power()
    print(f'current_data:{current_data}')
    print(f'previous_data: {previous_data}')
    print(f'Total Power: {total_power_reading()}')
    if previous_data == current_data:
        print("Emergency!!!!")
        lgpio.gpio_write(h,EMERGENCY,1)
    else:
        lgpio.gpio_write(h,EMERGENCY,0)

def switch_control():
        global sw
        global sw_control


        previous_sw = sw_control
        sw_control = blynk_switch.main()
        if len(sw_control) == 1:
            sw_control[1:5] = previous_sw[1:5]
        elif len(sw_control)==2:
            sw_control[2:5] = previous_sw[2:5]
        elif len(sw_control)==3:
            sw_control[3:5] = previous_sw[3:5]
        elif len(sw_control)==4:
            print(sw_control)
            sw_control[4:5] = previous_sw[4:5]
        elif len(sw_control)==0:
            sw_control[0:5] = previous_sw[0:5]

def power_monitoring():
    global sw_control, threshold
    print(f'Totap Power: {total_power_reading()}')

    if (total_power_reading()>threshold):
        current_power = get_current_power()
        num = current_power.index(max(current_power))
        sw_control[num] = '0'


def run_thread_power():
    thread_1 = Thread(target=get_current_power)
    thread_1.start()      

def run_thread_plug():
    thread_2 = Thread(target=plug_reading)
    thread_2.start()

def run_thread_blynk():
    thread_3 = Thread(target=blynk_control.main)
    thread_3.start()

schedule.every(2).seconds.do(run_thread_power)
schedule.every(20).seconds.do(run_thread_plug)
schedule.every(5).seconds.do(run_thread_blynk)


def main_1():
    # Loop to run the scheduler continuously
    global sw_control
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()

        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(control.plug_data(sw_control[0],sw_control[1],sw_control[2],sw_control[3],sw_control[4]))
        # get_from_blynk()
        print(f'Switch is {sw_control}')
        switch_control()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_1()

The resulted error is as shown below:
Error
Exception in thread Thread-260 (get_current_power):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/yslim/Desktop/IDP2024/plug_2.py", line 32, in get_current_power
    current_power = get_data()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/yslim/Desktop/IDP2024/plug_2.py", line 23, in get_data
    data = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(plug.plug_data())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/events.py", line 677, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-260 (get_current_power)'.
````your text`

